# python BeautifulSoup grab 'text format' child only

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="Title">
        SIZE
        <span class="required-option-group">
                (required)
        </span>
</div>
```

my code is: `name = soup.find('div', {'class':'Title'}).text.strip()`. 
It returns both 'SIZE' and '(required)', but I only want to grab 'SIZE'.

I believe it has a really easy approach, and just wondering if anybody could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can isolate the tag's direct text using another `.find(text=True)`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="Title">
        SIZE
        <span class="required-option-group">
                (required)
        </span>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div', {'class':'Title'}).find(text=True).strip())
```

Output

```
SIZE
```

Comment: ah, thank you a lot!